# How to add a single uniform trendline in a side by side bar chart in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have created a side by side bar in Tableau By using Measure names and measure values. I am using multiple measures to plot in the side by side bars. However I am not able to add a uniform trendline across the date in the entire chart  Please see picture below:

[image]

How do I add a trendline to the chart

Comment: Hi Sandeep.  Please share the data structure and some sample data.  Please also tell for which measure you want to add a trendline?

Comment: Hi I want to add a trendline for all measure . for data structure how do i share my tableau workbook with you?